# How to randomly change the Gnome background image using bash?

Tags: bash, gnome

I'm trying to set a random image as the Gnome background for the
current user using bash.

What I have found out:

- To set the wallpaper I can use:

  ```
  gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename "path_to_file.jpg";
  ```
- To get the path to a random wallpaper I can use:

  ```
  find /usr/share/backgrounds/scenery/ | grep jpg | shuf -n1;
  ```

The problem is: How do I put this two commands together to change the
wallpaper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bash construct `$(command)` will expand into the output of
`command`. You could use it thusly:

```
gconftool-2 --type string \
  --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename \
  "$(find /usr/share/backgrounds/scenery/ | grep jpg | shuf -n1)"
```

Note that I kept your `find` command exactly as you put it in your
question, but perhaps it would be better expressed as
`find path -type f -name '*.jpg'`.